# How can I get the index of an occurrence in a repeating event on the calendar month view?

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm using the calendar demo templates that came with Solspace Calendar ([documentation here](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.month/)). I've got a couple repeating events and I want to output the occurrence index (`Day 1`, `Day 2`, `Day 3`, etc.).

Here's the code for the specific day:

```
{% for entry in day.events %}
  <a href="{{ entry.title }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

From the docs, I'd think `occurrenceCount` to work, but it returns `0` for each event vs the index of the occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the position of the event inside the loop, so you can just use this:

```
{{ loop.index }}
```

If you're referring to which occurrence the event is (of the full series of recurrences of that event), then I don't think that is currently possible.

Comment: Yes, the latter. This would be on the calendar view. So think of a series of 3 days (repeating event). There a way I can request this formally?

Comment: I'm also looking for this functionality - has there been any updates to this?